# Hadoop BlockMissingException on AWS EMR Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-emr

I'm facing difficulties executing a job on Apache Spark within an AWS EMR (Elastic MapReduce) cluster. It's essential to note that the EMR cluster is provisioned exclusively for processing this specific job and is terminated immediately after completion.

The source file is copied into the EMR HDFS (Version 5.23.1) using the DistCpS3 step, and it's a single XML file of approximately 230 GB.

This XML file comprises three levels of tags. The first two layers are processed with Spark (version 2.4.0) without any issues. However, when attempting to process the last level, I encounter the following exception:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockMissingException: Could not obtain block: BP
```

How can I resolve this issue?

I tried to run a Spark job on EMR to transform an XML file into Parquet and encountered an hdfs.BlockMissingException.